# Como resolver o Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, meu site não está funcionando e dá o erro
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home2/amttli84/public_html/conexao.php on line 7**

O estranho é que no meu localhost funciona perfeitamente e está igual no servidor. Já tentei mudar o php.ini, reiniciar o servidor e não sei mais o que tentar.
Segue o código de conexao.php

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', (getenv('DB_HOST')  ?: '127.0.0.1'));
define('DB_USUARIO', (getenv('DB_USUARIO') ?: 'root'));
define('DB_SENHA', (getenv('DB_SENHA') ?: '1234'));
define('DB_NOME', (getenv('DB_NOME') ?: 'amtt'));

$conexao = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USUARIO,DB_SENHA,DB_NOME)
    or die ('Não foi possivel conectar'); <?php
```

https://prnt.sc/xr9kl5

E o arquivo de login é

```
    session_start();
    include('conexao.php');
    require_once "recaptchalib.php";
    //se um ou ambos dos campos estiverem vazios, retorna ao index
    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])){
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

    $secret = "6LdgJ70UAAAAAAQrtJVIRpZiMlZhkEV_0owP3i_C";

    $response = null;
    $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

    if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
        $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
    }

    if ($response != null) {
        //As variaveis recebem os dados vindos através do POST
        $usuarioLogado = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['usuario']);
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['senha']);

        //Busca no banco de dados se a senha e usuário informado combinam com algum registro
        $query= "select usuario_id, nivel_acesso from usuario where usuario = '{$usuarioLogado}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $resultadoFull = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($resultadoFull['nivel_acesso'] == 'sus'){

            $_SESSION['usuarioSuspenso'] = true;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }else

        //verifica se a senha e usuario informados estao corretos
        if($row == 1){
            $_SESSION['usuarioLogado'] = $usuarioLogado;
            $usuarioLogado = $_SESSION['usuarioLogado'];
            $query2 = "select * from usuario where usuario = '{$usuarioLogado}'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conexao,$query2);
            $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

            $_SESSION['nomeServidor']=$rows['nome'];
            $_SESSION['idServidor']=$rows['usuario_id'];
            $_SESSION['nivel_acesso']=$rows['nivel_acesso'];



            $administrador=$rows['administrador'];
            if($administrador =='sim'){
                $_SESSION['adm']=true;
            }else if($administrador =='vcg'){
                $_SESSION['vcg']=true;
            } else{
                $_SESSION['usuarioNormal']=true;
            }



            header('Location: painel.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        echo $response;
        $_SESSION['captchaInvalido'] = true;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD2X9.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O servidor de onde você está executando o código não possui o módulo `php_mysqli` instalado/habilitado.

Seguindo respostas [deste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect), se você estiver utilizando linux (ubuntu, mint, debian) apenas executar o seguinte comando no servidor resolverá:

`sudo apt install php-mysqli`

Na pasta de instalação do php procure pelo arquivo `php.ini` e edite a linha:

`; extension=mysqli` (comentado/desativado)

para

`extension=mysqli` (ativo)

Obs.: Também há algumas dicas na [documentação do php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) (em inglês) e [neste link](https://php.docow.com/como-habilitar-a-extensao-mysqli-no-php-7.html).

A forma com que é configurado o módulo também depende da versão do seu PHP e qual sistema operacional você está utilizando, caso as alterações acima não resolvam sugiro pesquisar como ativar ou instalar o módulo `php_mysqli` para a sua versão do PHP e seu sistema operacional escpecíficos.